# input not being sent to log

Tags: php, forms, file, logging, request

So here's the short story: I have a comment box that holds user input (like any regular comment box, I suppose). I want to send this user input to a log file. The problem is, this isn't happening.

This is what I have:

```
 if (isset ($_REQUEST['saving'])) {
    $saving = $_REQUEST['saving'];
    if ($saving ==1) {
    $comments = $_POST['comment'];
        $file = "logfile.txt";

    $fp = fopen($file, "w") or die ("Couldn't open $file for writing!");
    fwrite($fp, $comment) or die ("Couldn't write values to file!");

    fclose($fp);
    echo "Saved to $file successfully!";
    }
}
```

And the info that it's sending comes from :

```
<textarea name="comment" cols="80" rows="10">
<?php echo $comment; ?>
</textarea><br>
```

Where $comment is the user input.
I'm not getting any error messages, but when I open the logfile.txt, it is empty.

Any help would be G R E A T. I'm really stuck. Thanks in advance to all suggestions :-)

Comment: Have you echo'd out $saving to see what it's coming out as? Maybe it's bypassing the if statement completely.

Comment: @JesseKernaghan it looks like it; when I perform a var_dump nothing is printed to the page. Not sure why this is happening/how to fix it though

Comment: You could try switching to $_POST or $_GET depending on where the content is coming from. I don't know if it would make a difference though. Try echoing out a test right after the isset statement too.

Answer (score 0):

`fwrite($fp, $comment)` should be `fwrite($fp, $comments)`. This will work assuming you have your `<textarea>` properly inside a `<form>` element.

:)

Comment: Yep it is. And I changed the $comments to $comment (to be more concise, I've been calling it "comment" everywhere else). Still nothing in logfile.txt

Answer (score 0):

```
$comments = $_POST['comment'];
```

Should Be

```
$comment = $_POST['comment'];
```

Comment: Oh good catch -- changed that. Still nothing in logfile.txt though

Comment: @dynamic - the OP should change $comments to $comment where he is setting his value as he uses $comment elsewhere in the code, html, fwrite, etc.

Comment: @eigen93 - can you get a `var_dump($_REQUEST);` Let us know what the result is?

Comment: Yep, nothing is printed to the screen. Any ideas why this is happening ?

Comment: what type of server are you testing your application on, local, LAMP, godaddy, mediatemple, etc?